# Sublime Text: How to enable a package for 1 programming language only?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I am editing C file, the emmet is enabled.
I don't want that behavior.

How to disable package for language A when not using language A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Go to your `Emmet.sublime-settings` file.
2. Find where it says `"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes":`
3. Add `source.c` to the the value

---

It should end up looking something like this:

`"disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "source.c",`

Comment: This does not work, I don't know why. After restart, emmet still works in C files.

Comment: This issue is fixed, Thanks!